# Draggable snap to class but not to specific item

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-draggable

I try [Jquery UI Dragabble](http://jqueryui.com/draggable/), and I want to snap to a class of elements, but to not snap to an element which is part of that class (Sorry for my English).
I mean something like this:

```
$( "#selected" ).draggable({
    snap: ".elements",
    snapCancel: "#special_element"
})
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know if understand it correctly but you can try something like this:

```
$( "#selected" ).draggable({
    snap: ".elements:not(#special_element)"
});
```

[Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/cmzzfv32/)